# How to get matched value from objects collection in Lodash?

Tags: angular, lodash, angular-forms

```
private static getControlName(c: AbstractControl): string | null {
    const formGroup = c.parent.controls;

    return Object.keys(formGroup).find(name => c === formGroup[name]) || null;
}
```

What will be the equivalent of the above return statement in Lodash? I tried with .find and .pickBy (and some others too) but all seems to return an object instead of the value.

Comment: Have you tried `_.findKey(formGroup, c)`?

Comment: Thanks you @Markai. You saved my day!